# Calculate checksum for whole content of a device and add a progress bar

Tags: bash, shell-script, hashsum, zenity

I want to make a shell script, that lets the user select a mounted device and calculate a checksum for the whole data on this device. I need the checksum to test if the device has been manipulated by somebody else. My approach to this was like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "${0%/*}"



device=$(zenity --file-selection --directory \
--filename="/run/media/"${USER}"/"


zenity --info \
--title "Info Message" \
--width 500 \
--height 150 \
--text "$(find "$device" -type f -exec md5sum {} \; | sort -k 2 | md5sum | cut -d ' ' -f 1)"
```

**My questions are:**

1. Is this the right approach?
2. How can I add a progress bar between the selection of the device and the dialog box with the output of the calculation?

Comment: Related: [Wait until md5sum command is completed](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/722371)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pv`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pv.1.html) which allows you to monitor the progress of data through a pipe.

```
find "$device" -type f -exec md5sum {} \; | pv -ls $(find "$device" -type f |wc -l) | sort -k 2 | md5sum
```

- `-s <size>` provides the total size of the data. Since we want to show the progress according to the number of files, to need to know how many files are in the device, hence the `$(find "$device" -type f |wc -l)`.
- `-l` - Instead  of counting  bytes, count lines (newline characters).

The first `find` command will send the results of the md5sum to the `pv` command. `pv` will calculate the percentage done (the input lines divided by the total size provided by the `-s` flag), it will write the dialog the standard error of the terminal, and send it's input (the result of the first `find` command) to the next command after the pipe (in this case, `sort`).

```
$ find "$device" -type f -exec md5sum {} \; | pv -ls $(find "$device" -type f |wc -l) | sort -k 2 | md5sum | cut -d ' ' -f 1
6.77k 0:00:10 [1.61k/s] [=========>                            ] 28% ETA 0:00:24
```

If there are too many files on the device, and counting the number of files might also take a long time, you can just use `pv -l`, in which case it will not show the completed percentage and the ETA, and the process bar would move left and right only to indicate that data is moving.

```
$ find "$device" -type f -exec md5sum {} \; | pv -l  | sort -k 2 | md5sum | cut -d ' ' -f 1
5.64k 0:00:09 [1.72k/s] [        <=>                                           ]
```

In order to show the progress bar in a `zenity` window, you can do something as follows:

```
find "$device" -type f -exec md5sum {} \; \
| ( ( pv -nls $(find "$device" -type f |wc -l) 2>&1 1>&3 ) \
| zenity --progress --auto-close --text="md5sum progress..." 2>/dev/null ) 3>&1 \
| sort -k 2 | md5sum | cut -d ' ' -f 1
```

- `-n` flag for `pv` - Instead of giving a visual indication of progress, `pv` will give an integer percentage, one per line, on standard error.
- `2>&1` will redirect the `stderr` of the `pv` command (the percent count) to the `stdout` - which is the `stdin` of the `zenity` command, so the latter could read the percent count and display the progress bar.
- `1>&3` redirect the old `stdout` (the output of the `find ... md5sum` command) to a a new file descriptor 3, to separate it from the `stdin` of the `zenity` process.
- `3>&1` the redirects file descriptor 3 of the `pv` process (containing the output of the `find` command) back to `stdout`, which is the `stdin` of the `sort` command to continue the analysis.

And if you want to view the final `md5sum` output in another `zenity` window:

```
zenity --info \
--title "Info Message" \
--width 500 \
--height 150 \
--text \
"$(find "$device" -type f -exec md5sum {} \; \
| ( ( pv -nls $(find "$device" -type f |wc -l) 2>&1 1>&3 ) \
| zenity --progress --auto-close --text="md5sum progress..." 2>/dev/null ) 3>&1 \
| sort -k 2 | md5sum | cut -d ' ' -f 1)"
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to display this without a terminal, and use for example a zenity dialog window?

Comment: @stewie I've edited my answer